# Android : ViewFlipper Or ViewPager - Which is the better option?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewflipper

I am getting stuck in one stage. I have a total of 20 to 25 images that should get animated like `ViewPager` does. Now on all the images I have `onClick()` events and I don't know if I should work with `ViewPager` or `ViewFlipper`. I can implement both things, no issues here.

**What I Want :** I just want a suggestion that according to my problem which will be the best option, `ViewFlipper` or `ViewPager`?

**What I Have Searched :** I have gone through different links on StackOverflow, namely [How to improve the performance of ViewFlipper/ViewAnimator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7338351/how-to-improve-the-performance-of-viewflipper-viewanimator) and [ViewFlipper vs Fragments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9009071/viewflipper-vs-fragments), but I could not find the thing I want.

I have worked with `ViewPager` somewhat, but at that time there were just 3 or 4 `Fragments` I had to manage. If I were to use it to solve this problem I have to manage 25 `Fragments` this time. So I am wondering if there is a better solution available.

I have also done a little R & D on `ViewFliper` and know that it has only one `Activity` I have to manage but it does not have the animation accuracy that `ViewPager` has.

Please suggest me whether I should go for `ViewPager` or `ViewFlipper`?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

***Update*** *(from 5+ years old original post):*

Use [ViewPager2 from JetPack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2). That's it.

---

***I left original answer below but just for reference. Please do not use very old and not maintained widgets (like Gallery and [ViewFlipper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper) any more):***
Intro: On first thought, I would recommend *Gallery* widget instead of *ViewFlipper* but it is depreciated since JellyBean (API 16), probably because of bad recycling of non-visible elements implementation.

Answer: What u really should use now is [**ViewPager**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) or [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html). In your case (despite not too much given details) I think is better [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) because according to documentation:

> .. [HorizontalScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one
> child in it, containing the entire contents to scroll ..

On the other side for [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) you should implement [PagerAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html) to generate pages which will be shown in this view.

My final answer is *A*, [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) ;)

Hope u will find this helpful ;) Cheers

Comment: And why that is?

Comment: @Ewoks Can you elaborate on the answer? I don't understand much how you arrived at the conclusion of going for ViewPager instead of ViewFlipper :(

Comment: `ViewPager2` is better if you have huge number of items. `ViewPager2` is based on `RecyclerView`, it will recycle it's child instead of rendering it all at once.