# Android: which one is better, viewpager, gallery, horizontal scroll view ..... or?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-gallery, android-scrollview

I have a fragment and would like to add a gallery to it, but i saw that gallery was deprecated.....

To be more specific, I would actually like to have a horizontal list view, as i would like to customize the view (include a image and text in each row) and allow it to be srcollable.

Also the number of "rows" (if horizontal it's columns then....) changes with the database, so it's not static and i don't want to limit the number of "rows"

Google helped me to find some solutions: viewpager and other add-on library

But which one would be better?

I hope that I won't need to fix the code all the time in the future! THANKS!!!!

Comment: Look at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031558/android-viewflipper-or-viewpager-which-is-better-option