# view pager vs view flipper - when and why

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager, viewflipper

I would like to understand the when to choose between view pager and view flipper, technically there might be difference while implementing these two, but visually they appear same to me. Can anyone rip off these two. Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same question :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031558/android-viewflipper-or-viewpager-which-is-better-option

Comment: RIT Thanks or the link, I already look into the link but still am looking for some more points other than that of link.

Comment: Read it again, it is one the links with complete description difference of them

Comment: @VVB I also don't see enough points on the difference of ViewPager and ViewFlipper on the answer from the given link :(. Only these 2 points were mentioned: 1) HorizontalScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it, containing the entire contents to scroll, 2) On the other side for ViewPager you should implement PagerAdapter to generate pages which will be shown in this view; 
 Am I missing something?